# grpc python client authentication throwing SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, ssl, grpc, grpc-python

I am building one grpc based application with secure authentication,  is there any issue with grpc python client or i am missing anything ? because on documentation it don't say much things.

My environment is following:

```
OS: "Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
python 3.7
openssl V 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.13
grpcio==1.39.0
grpcio-tools==1.39.0
protobuf==3.17.3
```

I am always getting SSL_ERROR_SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

```
E0901 13:16:05.996420843   13512 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0901 13:16:06.495380631   13512 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0901 13:16:06.953751870   13512 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0901 13:16:07.407166253   13512 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grpc-client.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "grpc-client.py", line 11, in main
    response = stub.ApiEndpoint(request)
  File "/home/ggarg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/ggarg/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
```

my proto file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";

service Api{
    rpc ApiEndpoint(ApiRequest)  returns (ApiResponse);   
}

message ApiRequest{
    string name = 1;
    string message = 2;
}

message ApiResponse{
    string reply = 1;
}
```

server code is:

```
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import time
import api_pb2
import api_pb2_grpc
import os


class ChatBox(api_pb2_grpc.ApiServicer):

    def ApiEndpoint(self, request, context):
        response = api_pb2.ApiResponse()
        response.reply = "Hi {}, myself {} , Thanks for this message : {}".format(
            request.name, os.getenv("POD_NAME"), request.message)
        return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a gRPC server
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    with open('cert/server.key', 'rb') as f:
        private_key = f.read()
    with open('cert/server.crt', 'rb') as f:
        certificate_chain = f.read()
    server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(
        ((private_key, certificate_chain), ))

    # add the servier created above tp the server
    api_pb2_grpc.add_ApiServicer_to_server(ChatBox(), server)

    # listen on port 50051
    print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
    server.add_secure_port('[::]:50051', server_credentials)
    server.start()
    # since server.start() will not block,
    # a sleep-loop is added to keep alive
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(86400)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)
```

and client code is:

```
import grpc
import api_pb2_grpc
import api_pb2
import time

def main():
    request = api_pb2.ApiRequest(
        name="timus",
        message="You are awesome")

    response = stub.ApiEndpoint(request)
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('cert/server.crt', 'rb') as f:
        creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(f.read())
    #channel = grpc.secure_channel('www.timus.com:443', creds)
    channel = grpc.secure_channel('0.0.0.0:50051', creds)
    stub = api_pb2_grpc.ApiStub(channel)
    while True:
        main()
        time.sleep(2)
```

I used following openssl command to generate crt.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha512 -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

I pasted above code as a example. for simplicity i am using same certificate on client and server. Initially i used ca/server/client certificate differently but I was having this issue and just for testing i used server certificate on both client and server side. but still getting same issue ? did anyone encounter similar issue ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to assign the server certificate as the client's trust certificate. That will require the certificate to be a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate). You will have to check that.

Even if it is self-signed, it is not the usual way for us to establish TLS connections. That can leave your applications to man-in-the-middle attack. You will want to have your client set a trust certificate that is issued by a CA, and have the CA sign the server's certificate. That can make sure there is a trustworthy third-party making sure the authentication is good.

You will also make sure the syntax is correct(sorry I am not that familiar with the Python syntax). We allow certs, root certs in both client and server  for mutual TLS, but for single TLS, you only need to set certs for server, and root certs for client.

Comment: Thanks @Zhen Lian, Issue was with self signed certificate, its working perfectly now.